# How to invalidate a listview from another class

Tags: android, listview, dialog

When I call a Dialog from another Class which is not an Activity, I want to Invalidate the Listview from its calling Activity and NotifyDatasetChange the Adapter after dismissing the Dialog.

```
public class SingleAudioBook extends Activity {
    private ListView lv;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSingleSong);
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    MyDialog.callLoginDialog(SingleAudioBook.this);
}}}
```

and my dialog is:

```
public class MyDialog {
private static Dialog myDialog;
 public static void callLoginDialog(final Context c){
...
}
```

Comment: you can either use a magic or pass ListView references to this "another Class" ... knowing nothing about your current code and class hierarchy dosn't help with solution

Comment: Thanks, I have put my Login Dialog in another class. Is is obligatory to make it an Activity Dialog ? I want to Refresh the listview after user LOGIN procedure @selvin

Comment: You can create static reference of it and then check null then apply code.

Comment: @nkushwah Thanks for your answer, Inside the MyDialog class I should apply code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use static reference of listView and Adapter. Replace your declaration with following-

Your_Activity -

```
   public static BaseAdapter your_adapter_name;
    public static ListView your_lv_name;
```

Use in another class-

```
// refresh listview
if( Your_Activity.your_lv_name!=null && Your_Activity.your_adapter_name!=null )
{
        Your_Activity.your_adapter_name.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Your_Activity.your_lv_name.refreshDrawableState();
        Your_Activity.your_lv_name.invalidateViews();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how to reference them from another class? it cannot resolve lv_name from another class  if I don't declare it previously

Comment: Thanks, instead of giving Negative point you explained and taught me where I needed help